# Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.FN_Split”, or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I have following function which accepts the CSV & delimeter & splits it

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Split] (@String varchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))      
returns @temptable TABLE (orderId int,items varchar(max))        
as        
begin        
   declare @idx int   
   declare @i int=0     
   declare @slice varchar(8000)        
   declare @orderId int = 0 --<added a counter

    select @idx = 1        
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

   while @idx!= 0        
   begin        
       set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
       if @idx!=0        
           set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
       else        
          set @slice = @String        

       if(len(@slice)>0)   
           insert into @temptable(orderId, Items) values(@orderId, @slice)        
       set @orderId = @orderId+1 --<increment the counter

       set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
       if len(@String) = 0 break        
   end    
return        
end
```

& the stored procedure like this which uses the above function & inserts the result into the database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure3
(
 --@tableName nvarchar(max),
 @p_SourceText nvarchar(max),
 @p_Delimeter nvarchar(100)=','
)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
--select * from fn_ParseText2Table(@p_SourceText, @p_Delimeter)
--insert into Person values (@sql)
declare @i int=0
DECLARE @max int=3

while @i<=@max
begin
if @i=0
begin
set @sql='insert into Person values( select items from'+dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,  
 @p_Delimeter)+ 'as where orderId ='+0+')'
end

 else
  begin
   if @i=(@max-1)
    begin
 set @sql=@sql+'UNION select items from'+ dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,
                  @p_Delimeter)+' where orderId ='+@i+')'
    end
 else
  begin
   set @sql=@sql+'UNION select items from'+ dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,        
                 @p_Delimeter)+ 'where orderId ='+@i+') UNION'
      end
   end
   set @i=@i+1
end
END
```

But After Executing the Procedure I get The Following error:
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.FN_Split", or the name is ambiguous.
No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)

Please help to get out of it...

Comment: Select the result of `dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText, @p_Delimeter)` into a text variable and use that for your `@sql` string building.

Comment: Function dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText, @p_Delimeter) returns a TABLE, not a single variable, so the usage would be SELECT * FROM dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText, @p_Delimeter) and not SELECT dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText, @p_Delimeter)

Comment: The bug in the question *title* is a simple typo, but since `FN_Slit` doesn't appear anywhere else in the question, I'll just assume it's a transcription error and not the actual problem.

Comment: oh no I did type mistake function name is "FN_split" instead of "FN_slit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you did run the create script in the correct database.

Second, as @astander started mentioning, you are using the function results incorrectly.

Your function returns a table, not a value.  You'll need to execute the function as part of your sql statements, not during your build of ad hoc queries.  For example, this code:

```
 set @sql=@sql+'UNION select items from'+ dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,
                  @p_Delimeter)+' where orderId ='+@i+')'
```

would become:

```
set @sql = @sql+'UNION select items from dbo.FN_Split(' + @p_SourceText +', ' +
                  @p_Delimeter + ') where orderId =' + @i + ')'
```

Make similar changes everywhere you are currently referencing the function.

Comment: you must use `select` instead of `values` when inserting, since you are potentially inserting more than one value:  `Insert into person select items from dbo.FN_Split('111|Mitchell|Johnson,|')` where orderId = 0` Note you also need quotes around your csv item.

Answer (score 0):

I think to clarify the comment from astander

try your code like this :

```
while @i<=@max
begin
if @i=0
begin
set @sql='insert into Person select items from dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,  
 @p_Delimeter) where orderId = 00'
end

 else
  begin
   if @i=(@max-1)
    begin
 set @sql=@sql+'UNION select items from dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,
                  @p_Delimeter) where orderId ='+@i
    end
 else
  begin
   set @sql=@sql+'UNION select items from dbo.FN_Split(@p_SourceText,        
                 @p_Delimeter) where orderId ='+@i UNION'
      end
   end
   set @i=@i+1
end
END
```

Comment: parameters need to be concatenated dynamically; they shouldn't be literals.

Comment: oh yes but you can specify them with your exec or like described here upper. exec usp_spexecutesql @sql, N'@p_sourceText varchar(30)', p_sourcetext = 'value'

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was really a function missing when i exported data from one database to another. Can not be found in the destination database > Functions > Scalar-valued Functions. Then i created [dbo].[equals] and it worked. (copied from source database)