# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_IntCalc", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This Error appear when I try to call the user-defined function

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.fn_IntCalc", or the name is ambiguous

Here is the user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_IntCalc (@IntersetRate NUMERIC(6, 3) = 10,
                                @Amount       NUMERIC(18, 5),
                                @FromDate     DATE,
                                @ToDate       DATE)
RETURNS NUMERIC(18, 5)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @IntCalculated NUMERIC(18, 5)

      SELECT @IntCalculated = @Amount * ( ( @IntersetRate / 100.0 ) 
             * ( DATEDIFF(d, @FromDate, @ToDate) / 365.0 ) )

      RETURN ( ISNULL(@IntCalculated, 0) )
  END

GO
```

And The calling part is:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_IntCalc(DEFAULT,2000,'Mar 1 2008','Mar 10 2008')
```

Comment: It is working perfectly on my machine - `SQL Server 2014`.

Comment: Do you get this when executing or just intellisense in SSMS?

Comment: Did you create the function with the same credentials that you are using to execute it?  (Perhaps this is a permissions problem.)

Comment: You should probably [rewrite this as an inline TVF anyway](http://blog.falafel.com/improve-performance-of-t-sql-user-defined-functions-by-converting-scalar-ones-to-table-valued-ones/) as scalar UDFs are notoriously bad for performance.

Comment: Are you executing in the correct database context?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it is in the same context

Comment: did you mean that the USE 'database name' should be used in the query editor??

Comment: @Ibrahim - Either that or the selected database in the drop down must be the same as the database with the function (and the script has no `use` statements that change it)

Comment: @MartinSmith - I tried to set the USE statement in the query editor and that works now ,,, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_IntCalc(DEFAULT,2000,'Mar 1 2008','Mar 10 2008')
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

These answers may be useful, take a look at them:

- [Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.FN_Split”, or the name is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651608/cannot-find-either-column-dbo-or-the-user-defined-function-or-aggregate-dbo-f)
- [Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Splitfn", or the name is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091830/cannot-find-either-column-dbo-or-the-user-defined-function-or-aggregate-dbo-s?rq=1)